# Loading a Local Image for use in Windows 7 Phone App Testing

Tags: c#, image, windows-phone-7, load

All, I am very new to Windows Phone and really don't know where to be gin with this one. I wan't to load some test images into my Windows phone application (for testing purposes only). On my machine I have some JPEGs that I would like to loade into a `Canvas` which itself contains an `Image`. I know you can load from Local Storage like this

```
private void LoadFromLocalStorage(string imageFileName, string imageFolder)
{
    var isoFile = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
    if (!isoFile.DirectoryExists(imageFolder))
    {
        isoFile.CreateDirectory(imageFolder);
    }

    string filePath = Path.Combine(imageFolder, imageFileName);
    using (var imageStream = isoFile.OpenFile(
        filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    {
        var imageSource = PictureDecoder.DecodeJpeg(imageStream);
        image.Source = imageSource;
    }
}
```

but how to get the image from my machine into isolated storage? Sorry, I am a real noob :[.

Comment: Perhaps what you're trying to do is overkill. Couldn't you add some images to your project and assign it to the source property?

Comment: That would be great but I can find an example of doing this with JPEGs. If you could provide an example that would be mint!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have images inside a images folder in your application directory. Make sure you set Build Action to "Content"

```
public class Storage
{
    public void SaveFilesToIsoStore()
    {
        //These files must match what is included in the application package,
        //or BinaryStream.Dispose below will throw an exception.
        string[] files = {
        "images/img1.jpg", "images/img2.png"
    };

        IsolatedStorageFile isoStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();

        if (files.Length > 0)
        {
            foreach (string f in files)
            {
                StreamResourceInfo sr = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri(f, UriKind.Relative));
                using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(sr.Stream))
                {
                    byte[] data = br.ReadBytes((int)sr.Stream.Length);
                    SaveToIsoStore(f, data);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void SaveToIsoStore(string fileName, byte[] data)
    {
        string strBaseDir = string.Empty;
        string delimStr = "/";
        char[] delimiter = delimStr.ToCharArray();
        string[] dirsPath = fileName.Split(delimiter);

        //Get the IsoStore.
        IsolatedStorageFile isoStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();

        //Re-create the directory structure.
        for (int i = 0; i < dirsPath.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            strBaseDir = System.IO.Path.Combine(strBaseDir, dirsPath[i]);
            isoStore.CreateDirectory(strBaseDir);
        }

        //Remove the existing file.
        if (isoStore.FileExists(fileName))
        {
            isoStore.DeleteFile(fileName);
        }

        //Write the file.
        using (BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(isoStore.CreateFile(fileName)))
        {
            bw.Write(data);
            bw.Close();
        }
    }

}
```

Add the following codes in App startup

```
 private void Application_Launching(object sender, LaunchingEventArgs e)
    {
        Storage sg = new Storage();
        sg.SaveFilesToIsoStore();
    }
```

Comment: Can you extend your answer? I am now having some issue actually loading the image in using the line `StreamResourceInfo sr = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri(f, UriKind.Relative));`? it is setting `sr` to `null` and I am not sure why as I have lines like `new Uri("/Icons/appbar.questionmark.rest.png", UriKind.Relative)` and these work fine?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to use some sort of Isolated storage browser:

http://wptools.codeplex.com/